# Cannot Understand the Meaning of new int(2)

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

As a C++ learner, this question might be a stupid one, so I really appreciate your patience and advice. I got the following piece of code from a book about programming:

```
int *ptr
ptr = new int(2)
```

So why do we put parenthesis for 2? I know "new int" represent dynamic memory, but what does it mean for "new int(2)"?

Comment: 2 is used to initialize the allocated int.

Comment: Note that you are also missing `;` at the end of both lines and that you really should almost never use `new` in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(2)` is the initializer for the newly created `int` object. It has the same meaning as the initializer in a variable definition:

```
int x(2);
```

It initializes the object with the value `2`.

I suggest you use the brace-notation for initializers though, in most cases:

```
int x{2};
ptr = new int{2};
```

(These two methods of initialization have subtle differences, but due to sometimes surprising parsing with `()` and other issues I would recommend that for most cases. It is a complicated topic and not without other opinions, though.)